# Shall converversion specifier "%%" match white spaces

Tags: c, gcc, language-lawyer

According to the C standard the conversion specifier `%` is defines as:

> % Matches a single % character; no conversion or assignment occurs. The
> complete conversion specification shall be %%.

However this code:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int n;
    printf("%d\n", sscanf("     %123", "%% %d", &n));
    return 0;
}
```

compiled with gcc-11.1.0 gives the output 1 so apparently `%%` matched the `"     %"` of the string.

This seems to be a violation of "Matches a **single** % character" as it also accepted the spaces in front of the % character.

Question: Is it correct according to the standard to accept white spaces as part of `%%` directive?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf: "All conversion specifiers other than [, c, and n consume and discard all leading whitespace characters"

Comment: @Mat Thanks... that was the part of the standard that I missed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the C89 Standard, at least, "Input white-space characters [...] are skipped, unless the specification includes a `[`, `c`, or `n` specifier."  (That's an old version of the Standard, but it's the one I had handy.  But I don't imagine this has changed in more recent versions.)

Comment: Thanks - while this is well know to me from e.g. `%d` the word **single** kind of tricked me. This is obviously correct.

Comment: It means it doesn't match multiple `%` characters, not that it only consumes a single character from the input. But it's an easy misunderstanding.

Answer (score 4):

I looked at the [final C17 draft](https://web.archive.org/web/20181230041359/http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/abq/c17_updated_proposed_fdis.pdf) and there's actually a specific example showing that `%%` skips whitespace:

> **EXAMPLE 5** The call:
>
> ```
> #include <stdio.h>
> /* ... */
> int n, i;
> n = sscanf("foo %bar 42", "foo%%bar%d", &i);
> ```
>
> will assign to n the value 1 and to i the value 42 because input
> white-space characters are skipped for both the % and d conversion
> specifiers.